# How can I restrict Worpress' Automatically Paginate Post to only one post type?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the Wordpress [Automatically Paginating Post](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/automatically-paginate-posts/). My requirement is to paginate multiple post types. It works fine with post-type "post" but I have custom post types like "department", "information" and more. I want it to work for every post type. Can you help me to make it generic?

Here is my Code.

```
foreach ($content as $index => $paragraph ) {

    $paragraph_words = count( preg_split( '/\s+/', strip_tags( $paragraph ) ) );
    $word_counter += $paragraph_words;

    if ( $word_counter >= $num_words ) {

        $content[ $index ] .= '<!--nextpage-->';
        $word_counter = 0;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}

unset( $word_counter );
unset( $index );
unset( $paragraph );
unset( $paragraph_words );
break;
//Reunite content
$content = implode( "\r\n\r\n", $content );

//And, overwrite the original content
$the_post->post_content = $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue after hours of googling i have found the solution. Use a jquery plugin **imtech_pager**

Replace `'<!--nextpage-->'`
with This

```
'</span><span class="do-paginate">'
```

After replacing

paste this code and include **imtech_pager** JS and its css

```
    echo '<div id="content"><span class="do-paginate">' . $content . '</span></div><div 
    id="pagingControls" class="pagination_single"></div>';
     ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
                            var pager = new Imtech.Pager();
                            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                                pager.paragraphsPerPage = 1; // set amount elements per page
pager.pagingContainer = jQuery('#content'); // set of main container
                                pager.paragraphs = jQuery('.do-paginate', 
    pager.pagingContainer);
    // set of required containers
                                pager.showPage(1);
                            });
                        </script>
```

Comment: Yeah that i am actually looking for. Thanks